# ES6 function similar to map

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I came across on code which could be just like `map` function, but I don't understand all semantic. Look on this code:

```
const reduce = (reducer, accumulator) => arr => {
    const [first, ...rest] = arr
    return arr.length
     ? reduce(reducer, reducer(accumulator, first))(rest)
     : accumulator
}

reduce((accum, current) => [...accum, current * 2], [])([1, 2, 3]);
```

Could you explain me how this code works?

1. why `...accum` is first arg but should be last and exactly `...accum` means in this example?
2. why in `reduce` first reducer is invoke without any arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to understand what `reduce()` function does. Here's a great [article](https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/javascripts-map-reduce-and-filter).

In short, it is used to accumulate values from a list. Not necessarily a sum, but you use it an operations where you need a result based on all elements of a list.

Your code seems to be taking all elements from a list, and multiplying it by 2. This like `[...accum, current * 2]` basically creates an array with all the values from the `accum` array, and the multiplication result. (See [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))

1. it is destructuring the values in `accum`
2. it's not being invoked, it's being passed so that it can be invoked in the function.

In summary, `reduce` is a high order function that takes a function called `reducer` and calls it recursively. Now, the whole function can be rewritten to use only 1 `.reduce()` call, but since that's not what you're asking I won't play critic.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I know that .reduce() can make a job, but this question how better javascript understand